# How to filter rds events from 'aws rds describe-events'?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cli

If I run `aws --profile dev rds describe-events`,

I get output like these:

```
{
    "Events": [
        {
            "SourceIdentifier": "dev-important-data",
            "SourceType": "db-instance",
            "Message": "CloudWatch Logs Export enabled for logs [audit, error, general, slowquery]",
            "EventCategories": [],
            "Date": "2019-06-27T05:26:02.469Z",
            "SourceArn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:141888792464:db:dev-important-data"
        }
}
```

Is it possible to apply filter to the output such that I will only see events coming form a certain `SourceIdentifier`?

I tried

```
aws --profile dev rds describe-events --duration 1000 --filters "Name=SourceIdentifier,Values=dev-important-data"
```

but i got the error:

```
Unrecognized filter name: SourceIdentifier
```

Then I tried to use the value `Events.SourceIdentifier`, but still same kind of error: `Unrecognized filter name: Events.SourceIdentifier`

What is the right way to construct the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use `-source-identifier` and  `--source-type=db-instance` parameters